# How to load/find a JAR resource from inside GMaven script?

Tags: java, groovy, maven, gmaven-plugin

This is my [gmaven](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Home) script, which is trying to find and load a file located somewhere inside the provided dependency (it's a section of `pom.xml`):

```
[...]
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <configuration>
        <source>
          <![CDATA[
          def File = // how to get my-file.txt?
          ]]>
        </source>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>my-group</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
[...]
```

The `my-file.txt` is located in `my-group:my-artifact:1.0` JAR file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is very simple:

```
def url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("my-file.txt");
```

Then the URL will be in the following format:

```
jar:file:/usr/me/.m2/repository/grp/art/1.0-SNAPSHOT/art.jar!/my-file.tex
```

The rest is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in the Jar, then it's technically not a file, but a Jar entry. Which means you have these possibilities:

- Load it as an `InputStream` using either the
  ClassLoader or manual Jar processing
- Extract it to a file (perhaps with [`dependency:unpack`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) or [`dependency:unpack-dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html))

Comment: could you please give a more specific answer/example? I think I understand the strategy, but can't implement it. Although it should be 3-4 lines of code...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to resolve the path to a jar to an external repository, but assuming the jar is in your local repository then you should have access to that via the `settings.localRepository` implicit variable. You then known your group and artifact id already, so the path to your jar, in this case would be `settings.localRepository + "/my-group/my-artifact/1.0/my-artifact-1.0.jar"`

This code should allow you to read in the jar file and get the text file from it. Note I wouldn't normally write this code to read a file into a byte[] myself, I just put it here for completeness. Ideally use something from apache commons or a similar library to do it:

```
    def file = null
    def fileInputStream = null
    def jarInputStream = null
    try {
        //construct this with the path to your jar file. 
        //May want to use a different stream, depending on where it's located
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("$settings.localRepository/my-group/my-artifact/1.0/my-artifact-1.0.jar")
        jarInputStream = new JarInputStream(fileInputStream)

        for (def nextEntry = jarInputStream.nextEntry; (nextEntry != null) && (file == null); nextEntry = jarInputStream.nextEntry) {
            //each entry name will be the full path of the file, 
            //so check if it has your file's name
            if (nextEntry.name.endsWith("my-file.txt")) {
                file = new byte[(int) nextEntry.size]
                def offset = 0
                def numRead = 0
                while (offset < file.length && (numRead = jarInputStream.read(file, offset, file.length - offset)) >= 0) {
                  offset += numRead
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e)
    }
    finally {
        jarInputStream.close()
        fileInputStream.close()
    }
```

Comment: @Melv thanks for the example, but the problem is where to get `my-artifact.jar` location. The rest is trivial. Do you know how I can get this name inside my Groovy script?

Comment: @yegor256 I've updated the post above to do what I think you need it to do. Hope it's what you're after. I knocked up a quick test script locally and successfully read in a text file contained inside a jar in my repository with it.

Comment: @Melv looks like a very dirty approach, isn't it? The JAR is in `classpath` already, this is where we need to look for it. Can you explain how to get it out of there (in Groovy)?

Comment: You're trying to read a text file out of a dependent jar during your maven build and you're hoping for a clean solution? In my solution, your dependency on that jar is all coupled in your gmaven script. It's the cleanest solution I can think of to a dirty problem. Anyway, good luck, I bow out. Hope you find a solution you're happy with.

Comment: @Melv take a look at the answer I posted.

Comment: Ah, fair play. Didn't know you could do that. +1, good answer.